# How to check screen is running?

Tags: python, gnu-screen

How to check in Python whether the screen with the given name. For example, check if server1 is running?

Thanks : )

Comment: What do you mean by “screen”?

Comment: Are you referring to [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/)?

Comment: Ok.  Are you referring to GNU screen?

Comment: Assuming the answer is yes, I've re-tagged your question.

Answer (score 5):

The built in command for finding current screen sessions is `screen -ls`

To get the same functionality in python:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def screen_present(name):
        var = check_output(["screen -ls; true"],shell=True)
        if "."+name+"\t(" in var:
                print name+" is running"
        else:
                print name+" is not running"

screen_present("server1")
```

A couple of comments on the code:

- I had to use `; true` and `shell=True` because screen returns a exit code of `1`, which doesn't play well with the `check_output` function.
- Also, I added the `"."+` and `+\t(` to make sure that we were matching the screen name and not another part of the printout.

Answer (score 3):

you could use subprocess and pgrep:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output(['pgrep', '-f', 'screen'])
print p
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, what are you trying to achieve? You know that you can simply reattach a running screen session, do you?

```
screen -DRS admin # creates a new session if it isn't running
```

Likewise use `screen -x -S admin` to *share* the `admin` session without force-detaching the connected user(s).

---

#### Direct answer:

You can simply use the output of

```
screen -ls
```

which lists all running sessions, showing whether they are attached as well:

```
There are screens on:
        6675.third      (11/04/2011 09:25:49 PM)        (Attached)
        6668.pts-2.koolu        (11/04/2011 09:25:38 PM)        (Attached)
        6644.admin      (11/04/2011 09:25:21 PM)        (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-sehe.
```

Comment: `subprocess.check_call("screen -ls | grep -q 'srv%s'" % screen, shell=True)` -- be sure to sanitize input for the `screen` name because of security risks (imagine an attacker putting `; rm -rf /*` as the screen name :))