# Get name of current screen session

Tags: python, linux, bash, gnu-screen

How to get current screen session name (bash)?
I need implement it in Python, so would be much more better just command without Ctrl combinations.

I know way with `screen -ls | grep 'Attached'` but it's not elegant and sometimes not correct

Comment: See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479683/how-do-i-display-the-current-session-name-or-sockname-of-a-screen-session-in). Maybe it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get currently attached screen session name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16848940/608639), [How to check screen is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8015163/608639), [How can I tell whether I'm in a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5392618/608639), [Checking if a Screen of the Specified Name Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12255388/608639), [How do I use the “screen” command if I don't know what the ps or tty the program came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216003)

Answer (score 3):

Screen stores the session name in the env var `STY`. So you can access it as `os.environ['STY']`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['STY']
'17136.pts-3.suni-lnx'
```

Comment: If you also need to handle the case of not being in a screen session at all I'd recommend using `os.getenv('STY')` which will return `None` if the `$STY` variable doesn't exist in your environment